# Display the position of a feature/polygon borders while editing it

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature displayed on the map which can be modified. And I wish to be able to see the exact coordinate of the feature when hovering on it with the little indicator. I tried using

```
ol.control.MousePosition
```

like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Almia/qpqnrsnb/

But it’s not precise enough. When you circle around the dot it gives a different coordinate (which I suppose it only gives the exact data of where the mouse is)

[image]

What allows me to get the exact coordinate of the feature/polygon borders when hovering on it with the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I've found the solution. When you activate the modify interaction to a feature, the little dot used to guide you is a feature by itself. And his geometry type is a Point. So I did an event on ***pointermove*** to catch a point coordinates.

Here's the fiddle example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Almia/w3czqfof/)

```
 map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) return;

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    evt.pixel,function(feature, layer){return feature;}
  );

  if(feature){
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point') {
      var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      coord = ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

      document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = coord[0]+' ; '+coord[1];//the display
    }

  } 
});
```